# Discord Bot crashed after some time

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So I have a discord bot which works perfectly fine, but after some time (about 30 minutes) the bot crashes with this error message:

```
Error: Unhandled "error" event. ([object Object])
   at Client.emit (events.js:186:19)
   at WebSocketConnection.onError (C:\Users\Paul\Desktop\Hype-Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:374:17)
   at WebSocket.onError (C:\Users\Paul\Desktop\Hype-Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:128:16)
   at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
   at WebSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
   at _receiver.cleanup (C:\Users\Paul\Desktop\Hype-Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:211:14)
   at Receiver.cleanup (C:\Users\Paul\Desktop\Hype-Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:557:13)
   at WebSocket.finalize (C:\Users\Paul\Desktop\Hype-Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:206:20)
   at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
   at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
   at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
   at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
   at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
```

Does someone know how to solve this?

Comment: I looks like a WebSocket connection is closed. Is the bot losing Internet access?

Comment: Have you tried removing large chunks of your code one at a time to determine what part might be causing this?

Comment: @rockhopper72 The Bot is currently running on my pc and it didn't loose the connection once.

Comment: Can you give us some heads up on which part of the code might be the one causing error? What all is your bot used for?

Comment: You should log client errors: `client.on('error', console.error)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been looking for someone who needs some help with this sort of thing, and lo and behold here you are. I too have run into this issue. You have a network error that happens when your bot sends something called a `heartbeat` to the servers to say to them: `i am online`. Then the server will send it back. If it is sent and there is not a message returned from the server then it will give you your error. All you have to do is go into the following path in your bot folder `/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js`
Then in that file go to a section that looks like this:

```
onError(error) {
    if (error && error.message === 'uWs client connection error') {
      this.reconnect();
      return;
    }
    /**
     * Emitted whenever the client's WebSocket encounters a connection error.
     * @event Client#error
     * @param {Error} error The encountered error
     */
    this.client.emit(Constants.Events.ERROR, error);
  }
```

and what I did is change it to this:

```
onError(error) {
    if (error && error.message === 'uWs client connection error') {
      this.reconnect();
      return;
    }
    console.log("Attempting to reconnect!")
    return this.reconnect()
    /**
     * Emitted whenever the client's WebSocket encounters a connection error.
     * @event Client#error
     * @param {Error} error The encountered error
     */
    this.client.emit(Constants.Events.ERROR, error);
  }
```

I hope this helps!

Wishing you luck,

Zaedus

Comment: No problem, I figured this out recently and nobody knew about it! Glad I could help :D